# unable to get the variables from innerHTML in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

i am new to symfony2. I am designing a dynamic form builder. I have fetching a templete which shows the dynamic form and generates the code for that form in a text area for fetching the template i am using the following code:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
}
```

when click on submit, i want to fetch the code of that innerHTML in the text area ( i want to fetch the value of the random text area in the new templete). I am using the following code for fetching the new template what should I do to get that dynamic value.

```
public function subAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:sub.html.php',array(''));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to access

```
$request->request->get('name_of_the_textarea')
```

in the controller. You might also consider using the [Form Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) for that purpose.

Comment: in which controller, index or sub

Comment: The one where you receive the submitted value, i.e. sub.

Comment: should i write like this 
  $c= $request->request->get('source');
  return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:sub.html.php',array('name'=>$c));

Comment: but it is returning a blank page only

Comment: now i am getting the response as POST /Symfony/web/app_dev.php/task_new/ HTTP/1.1
Accept:          text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:   max-age=0
Connection:      keep-alive
Content-Length:  7
Content-Type:    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:          mediatabs=4; PHPSESSID=uhfh1jtronkenr263v0g38j8p0
Host:            localhost
Origin:          http://localhost
Referer:         http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/task/
Us